# Display result of program in quickfix list

Tags: vim

I want to compile a program inside of Vim, run it, and display the output in the quickfix list. I think this should work:

```
:cgetexpr "!cc -o %:r % && ./%:r"
```

However, that just displays the following in the quickfix list:

```
|| !cc -o %:r % && ./%:r
```

I also tried:

```
:cgetexpr execute "!cc -o %:r % && ./%:r"
```

This throws an error:

```
E121: Undefined variable: execute
E15: Invalid expression: execute "!cc -o %:r % && ./%:r"
```

A similar error is shown if I omit the quotes:

```
:cgetexpr execute !cc -o %:r % && ./%:r
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `:help :cexpr` says, the expression following `:cexpr` may be either a string or a list. None of the expressions you've tried evaluate to a string or list of the output of `cc`. However, `:help :cexpr` gives an example that may help you.

```
:cexpr system('grep -n xyz *')
```

`:cgetexpr` is just like `:cexpr` but doesn't jump to the first error.

I verified that

```
:cgetexpr system("cc hello.c")
```

works, but getting variables into that command is a little more work. The following inserts the name of the current file into the command.

```
:exe 'cgetexpr system("cc '.expand('%').'")'
```

Comment: I ended up with `exe "cgetexpr system('cc -o ".expand("%:r")." ".expand("%")." && ".expand("%:r")."')"`.